# passing in object by ref

Tags: c#, .net, ref

What is the difference between

```
public function Foo(ref Bar bar)
{
   bar.Prop = 1;
}

public function Foo(Bar bar)
{
   bar.Prop = 1;
}
```

essentially what is the point of "ref".  isn't an object always by reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is that you never actually pass an *object*. You pass a *reference* - and the argument itself can be passed by reference or value. They behave differently if you change the parameter value itself, e.g. setting it to `null` or to a different reference. With `ref` this change affects the caller's variable; without `ref` it was only a *copy* of the value which was passed, so the caller doesn't see any change to their variable.

See [my article on argument passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: I guess you mean "the argumetn itself can be passed by reference or value" and not "by parameter or value". Or is my vocabulary wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. But if you were to do this:

```
public function Foo(ref Bar bar)
{
   bar = new Bar();
}

public function Foo(Bar bar)
{
    bar = new Bar();
}
```

then you'd see the difference. The first passes a reference to the reference, and so in this case bar gets changed to your new object. In the second, it doesn't.