# Passing List<int> by ref

Tags: c#, ref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing in object by ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729526/passing-in-object-by-ref)

With the code below, the output would be:

```
Without:
With:1
```

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listWithoutRef = new List<int>();
        WithoutRef(listWithoutRef);
        Console.WriteLine("Without:" + string.Join(" ", listWithoutRef));

        var listWithRef = new List<int>();
        WithRef(ref listWithRef);
        Console.WriteLine("With:" + string.Join(" ", listWithRef));
    }

    static void WithoutRef(List<int> inList)
    {
        inList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1 });
    }

    static void WithRef(ref List<int> inList)
    {
        inList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1 });
    }
```

By just looking at this, I would have said that a List is on the Heap, and so is passed by ref anyway, so they should be the same? Am I misunderstanding the ref keyword? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing in object by ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729526/passing-in-object-by-ref)  -- Jon Skeet's answer on that question explains the case when you don't change the object, but assign a brand new object.  Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the ref keyword? Or am I missing something else?

Yes.  You're not passing the list itself to the method, but rather passing the *reference to the list* by reference.  This lets you change the reference (the `List<int>` that `listWithRef` actual refers to) within the method, and have it reflect.

Without using the `ref` keyword, your method can't change the reference to the list - the actual list storage mechanism is unchanged in either case.

Note that this isn't required if you just want to *use* the list.  You can call `List<int>.Add` within either method, for example, and the list will get new items added to it.  Ref is only required with reference types to change the reference itself.

Comment: You couldn't find an existing answer to this question?

Comment: @BenVoigt I voted to close, as well - but still answered it anyways

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all of the `List` objects are stored on the heap either way.  However, without the `ref` keyword, you can't reassign the `inList` parameter and have it affect the caller's scope.  When you create a new `List` object, it goes on the heap as a new object, but the original **reference** in the caller's scope is not affected unless you use the **ref** keyword.

In `WithoutRef`, if you call methods on the existing `List` without redefining it, you will see that it is modified:

```
inList.Clear();
inList.Add(1);
```